# Using the definition of a limit; fraction function

Tags: limits

I have looked around the forums trying to find a question similar to my own, but to no avail. I really struggle to grasp the epsilon-delta proofs, and my assignment calls for one. I have tried to use the epsilon-delta proof and have failed quite miserably, I won't bother posting my working of it as it's a complete mess. I have made up a similar equation to my assignment for ethical reasons:

> Using the definition of a limit, show that $\frac{9x-14}{3x^2 +7}$ approaches $\frac{2}{5}$ as $x$ approaches $3.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate you changing the problem from your homework problem rather than just pasting it in.
Epsilon/delta proofs require a two-stage process. First you estimate in scratch work, and then you write it up so your estimations work out exactly right.

### Scratch work

Let $f(x) = \frac{9x-4}{3x^2+7}$ and $a = \frac{7}{2} = 3.5$.  Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-a| < \delta$.  In this case:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(a)| 
&= \left| \frac{9x-14}{3x^2+7} - \frac{2}{5} \right|
 = \left| \frac{5(9x-14)-2(3x^2+7)}{5(3x^2+7)}\right| 
\\&= \left| \frac{45x-70-6x^2-14}{5(3x^2+7)}\right|
   = \left| \frac{45x-6x^2-84}{5(3x^2+7)}\right|
\\&= \left| \frac{(-3)(x-4)(2x-7)}{5(3x^2+7)}\right|
   = \frac{6}{5} \cdot |x-4| \cdot \frac{1}{3x^2+7} \cdot \left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right|
\end{align*}
When doing limit proofs with rational functions and simplifying $|f(x)-f(a)|$, you should always end up with a factor of $|x-a|$.  That factor is the one part we can control directly; and controlling it can affect estimates of the other factors.

For instance, suppose we know that $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| \leq 1$.  Then
\begin{gather*}
    - 1 \leq x- \frac{7}{2} \leq 1 
\\\implies \frac{5}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{9}{2} 
\\\implies -\frac{3}{2} \leq x-4 \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{gather*}
This gives upper and lower bounds for $x-4$, and we want an upper bound for $|x-4|$.  The inequality $|x-4| \leq M$ is equivalent to $-M \leq x-4 \leq M$.  We can't say $|x-4| \leq\frac{1}{2}$, because that would be equivalent to $-\frac{1}{2} \leq x-4 \leq \frac{1}{2}$, and that's not guaranteed by the work above (it's not true at $x=3$, for instance).  But 
$$
    -\frac{3}{2} \leq x-4 \leq \frac{1}{2}
    \implies -\frac{3}{2} \leq x-4 \leq \frac{3}{2}
    \implies |x-4| \leq \frac{3}{2}
$$

For the other factor,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{5}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{9}{2}
\\\implies \frac{25}{4} \leq x^2 \leq \frac{81}{4} 
\\\implies \frac{75}{4} \leq 3x^2 \leq \frac{343}{4} 
\\\implies \frac{103}{4} \leq 3x^2 + 7 \leq \frac{371}{4}
\\\implies \frac{4}{103} \geq \frac{1}{3x^2 + 7} \geq \frac{4}{371}
\end{gather*}
So we have an upper bound for $\frac{1}{3x^2 + 7}$, namely $\frac{4}{103}$.

If *additionally* $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta$ for some $\delta$, then
$$
    |f(x) - f(a)| < \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{103} \cdot \delta
    = \frac{36}{515}\delta
$$
OK, that's a nasty fraction, but it is just a constant multiple of $\delta$.  Now we remember that we can choose $\delta$ as small as we like to make sure the difference above is $< \epsilon$.  For instance, if $\delta \leq \frac{515}{36}\epsilon$, it seems like we're done.

Except for one small point: we had to assume $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| \leq 1$ to get started.  So we had also make sure that $\delta \leq 1$ in order to guarantee that $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| \leq 1$.  We can't let $\delta$ be both $\frac{515}{36}\epsilon$ and $1$, but we can let it be the **minimum** of those two.  Then both $\delta \leq  \frac{515}{36}\epsilon$ and $\delta \leq 1$ are guaranteed.

### Writeup

Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min\left\{1,\frac{515}{36}\epsilon\right\}$.  Notice that for any $x$, 
$$
    \left| \frac{9x-14}{3x^2+7} - \frac{2}{5} \right|
    = \dots = \frac{6}{5} \cdot |x-4| \cdot \frac{1}{3x^2+7} \cdot \left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right|
$$
(where $\cdots$ is, you want to substitute the work you did to get there)

Suppose $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta$.  Then
$$
    \left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| \leq 1 \implies \dots \implies |x-4| < \frac{3}{2}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
    \left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| \leq 1 \implies \dots \implies \frac{1}{3x^2 + 7} \leq \frac{4}{103}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \frac{6}{5} \cdot |x-4| \cdot \frac{1}{3x^2+7} \cdot \left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right|
    < \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{103} \cdot \delta
    < \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{103} \cdot \frac{515}{36}\epsilon = \epsilon
$$
QED

---

This trick of first estimating $\delta \leq 1$ will work in a lot of these rational function limit proofs.  You can estimate any expression in $x$ if you have an estimate of $x$.

### Are we done?  Why?

How does this actually establish the limit?  Remember the definition:

> $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if **for every** $\epsilon > 0$ **there exists** a $\delta > 0$ such that (**for all** $x$) **if** $0<|x-a| < \delta$ **then** $|f(x) - L|< \epsilon$.

The bolded phrases are the universal (“for all/every”) and existential (“there exists ... such that”) quantifiers.  In a more conversational tone, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ means that no matter what $\epsilon$ you give me, I can find a $\delta$ such that any $x$ that is within $\delta$ of $a$ (with the possible exception of $a$) satisfies the inequality $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

The outline of our proof is:

> **Given** $\epsilon > 0$, **let** $\delta = \dots$.  **Suppose** $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta$ (for some $x$).  **Then** *...yada yada yada...*  $\left|f(x) - \frac{2}{5}\right| < \epsilon$.

The definition says “for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$” and the proof reads “Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta = $(this thing).” In other words, the prover dares you to give him any positive $\epsilon$, no matter how small, and is able to produce a corresponding $\delta$.

Such a $\delta$ is admissible if the inequality $|f(x) - L| <\epsilon$ can be derived from the inequality $|x-a|<\delta$ alone.  The prover sets out to do this, first showing that $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta\implies \left|x-4\right|< \frac{3}{2}$, then that $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta\implies \frac{1}{3x^2 + 7} <\frac{4}{103}$, and finally, by comparing each factor, that $\left|x-\frac{7}{2}\right| < \delta\implies \left| \frac{9x-14}{3x^2+7} - \frac{2}{5} \right| < \epsilon$.  That is what is needed to be demonstrated (*quod erat demonstratum* in Latin, abbreviated QED) to show that the definition is satisfied.

Comment: I'm taking a break for tonight (almost midnight here) but I just wanted to say thanks and this seems absolutely like what I was looking for! And about changing the question, I feel if I just get someone to hold my hand through exactly the question I need I won't learn as much! If I can understand conceptually through the example I've given and then apply it to my own then I will be much better off!

Comment: I am working through it now. Can you clarify why you chose 3/2 in the first factor, and 4/371 in the next?

Comment: Ah. I've made a mistake with my suggested edit. I realise you meant to do that.

Comment: Or did you? Did you mean for the rest of the "1755" to be 1855? As it seems intuitive to make 2 ≤ ε ≤ε/2

Comment: @Skylineblue: I didn't “choose” $3/2$ in the first factor.  It follows from the condition that $|x-7/2| < 1$.  The same for the $4/371$; it's a necessary consequence of $|x-7/2| < 1$.  I did mistakenly switch the $1855$ to $1755$ though.  That's just a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I missphrased it. Why is it you chose 3/2 over 1/2? And then 4/371 over 4/103?

Comment: And also, is the concluding line really the justification that the function approaches 2/5 as x approaches 3.5? I'm still a bit confused by these questions and don't quite understand how exactly this proves anything?

Comment: @Skylineblue: Now I understand your question.  I've edited.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much, Matthew.

Comment: Was just going through this once more and noticed that when you take the reciprocal of the inequality, you do not change the signs. I'm not good with editing the formatting, but just wanted to point this out.

Comment: @Skylineblue: Oh, I can't believe I missed that!  That changes a lot of the constants.  But it doesn't change the basic argument.

Comment: @Skylineblue: fixed, I think.

Comment: Looks like it's all correct now!